# whats wrong with my functions

Tags: c++

```
void getLottoPicks()
{
    int i,k, num[7], num1;

    bool nodup(int num[7],int k, int num1), noover= true;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
        num[i]=51;

    cout << "please enter the seven numbers you think will win the lottery: "<< endl;
    for (i=0; i<7;i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
        if(num[i] < 1 || num[i] > 40)
        {
            i= i-1;
            noover = false;
            cout << "The number is out of range. Please enter a new number ";
        }

        if(noover)
        {
            num1=num[i];
            k=i;
            if (!nodup(num,k, num1))
            {   
                i=i-1 ;
                cout <<" you type the duplicated number. please enter another number"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
bool nodup(int num[7],int i, int num1)
{
    bool dup = false;
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<i-1; k++)
    {
        if (num[k] = num1)
            dup = true;
    }
    return !dup;
}
```

every time i enter 2 of the same number it always couts " you type the duplicated number. please enter another number";

Comment: Try running it under a debugger.

Comment: What's the desired behavior? Other than not resetting noover, this looks about right.

Comment: "every time i enter 2 of the same number it always couts ' you type the duplicated number. please enter another number'"

I assume you're doing this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972902/i-need-help-with-my-lottery-program

Read the assignment again.  It that is what it's supposed to do.

Comment: i was able to fix everything thanks to you guys THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this line is wrong:

```
    if (num[k] = num1)
```

I think what it should be is:

```
    if (num[k] == num1)
```

Comment: @paul kee - well, it's definitely one problem

Comment: sorry but when i enter a 1 and right after i enter 1 again it wont detect it, but if i enter 1 then 2 then 1 itll detect it

Comment: @paul kee - see my answer. you have your array indexes wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`bool nodup(int num[7],int k, int num1), noover= true;`

I can honestly say that I don't think that I've *ever* seen a forward declaration like this before (not that this post helps you at all ;))

Comment: Yes, this is something that I am sure the OP isn't aware of either :) It just works.

Answer (score 3):

You are filling your array starting at different positions.  In the getLottoPicks() you are starting with 1 and in nodup() you start at 0.  In C++ you generally start arrays at 0.

Comment: so i made these corrections but when i enter 1 and right after i enter 1 again it doesnt detect that its a duplicate

Comment: Did you make this change `for(k=0; k <= i ; k++)  //in nodup function`?

Answer (score 1):

There is another issue: the for loops in getLottoPicks() start from 1 while that of nodup() starts from 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems in your code technically and aesthetically.

1. Your for loop `for (i=1; i<7;i++)` is wrong. This will only run 6 times. You should try starting it with `i=0`.
2. Instead of doing a forward declaration like: `bool nodup(int num[7],int k, int num1), noover= true;`, either move your forward declaration before the method `getlottopicks` or move the whole method `nodup` before lotto picks. This somehow doesn't seem easy on the eye.
3. `if (num[k] = num1)` is wrong. Replace it with `if (num[k] == num1)`
4. use `i--` instead of `i=i-1` and use `continue` instead of using a variable `noover`.

Fix these and your code will be a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously with `if (num[k] = num1)` which should be written as `if (num[k]== num1)`.    That is, change the assignment operator to equality operator.

Also the `for` loop's condition should be this:

```
for(k=0; k <= i ; k++)  //in nodup function
       //^^^^^^ I think you want this!
```

And in `getLottoPicks` the loop should be this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i<7;i++)
    //^^^^ start from zero
```

---

By the way, if I understood your code (and the job it does) correctly, then I think you should use `std::set` which automatically solves many problems. First and foremost is, `std::set` always checks for duplicate before adding new item to itself. That means, every item in `std::set` is unique.

Consider using : [`std::set<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)

If you use `std::set<int>`, your code would reduce to this:

```
#include <set>

void getLottoPicks()
{
    set::set<int> nums;
    int input;
    while(nums.size() < 7)
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input < 1 || num > 40 )
        {
            std::cout << "Out of range. Please enter number between [1-40] : ";
        }
        else if(nums.insert(input).second == false)
        {
            std::cout <<"Duplicate number. Please try again : "; 
        }
    }
}
```

And you don't need `nodup()` function anymore.